# web3js later versions. Bundle, how?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I'm trying to build the frontend of a dApp, but the web3js makes my head hurt. I need to include it in my project, but the latest web3.min.js i can find is [this](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js). I want to use 1.2.1, and i understand that i need to bundle it together using browserify or something like that and then adding it as a js script.
Do any of you guys know of a guide to explain how i bundle together web3?

many thanks.

Comment: You can `npm install truffle`, then have a look at the files `cli.webpack.config.js`, `chain.bundled.js` and `cli.bundled.js` (under `/node_modules/truffle`). They probably did pretty much what you need (only with web3.js v1.0.0.beta-37 if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 0):

A minified version of the library is always in the `dist/` folder in the git repo. Here's the file for version 1.2.1:

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/v1.2.1/dist